# Proof: $a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$ holds $\forall a,b \in R$ iff R is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, ring-theory, proof-verification

We want to show that for some ring $R$, the equality $a^2 - b^2  = (a-b)(a+b)$ holds $\forall a,b \in R$ if and only if $R$ is commutative.

Here's my proof --- I'm not sure if the first part stands up to examination. I'd be grateful if someone could take a look.

Forward: $a^2 -b^2 = (a-b)(a+b) \forall a,b \in R$ implies $R$ is commutative

Let $x = (a-b)$. Then \begin{align}
x(a+b) &= xa+xb\\
&= (a-b)a + (a-b)b\\
&= a^2 -ba + ab - b^2\end{align}

Then we note that $a^2 - ba + ab - b^2 = a^2 - b^2$ iff $-ba + ab = 0$ if and only if $ab=ba$ iff $R$ is commutative.

Backwards: $R$ is commutative implies $a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b) \forall a,b \in R$.

Let $x = (a+b)$. Then $(a-b)x = ax - bx = a(a+b) - b(a+b) = a^2 + ab - ba - b^2$. $R$ is commutative, so $ab-ba = 0$, so $a^2 + ab - ba - b^2 = a^2 - b^2$.

Comment: $$x(a+b) = xa+b$$ I believe you *meant* to say $$x(a+b) = xa+xb$$

Comment: Btw which part are you not sure stands up to examination? The whole thing looks pretty solid to me.

Comment: It looks correct, but it could be made shorter

Comment: One more typo though. Last line, you write $a^2+b^2$. get that corrected

Comment: My god, that's a lot of typoes. I was copying from my hand-written notes.

Comment: @Newb there are even more. Should I take the liberty to do it myself?

Comment: And one question, are the 'iff' s some special notation? Like short for "if and only if"? There seem to be a lot of that.

Comment: @Sabyasachi yes

Comment: @Newb check now. Corrected two instance of + with - Changed one iff to cross the 6 char threshold.

Comment: @Sabyasachi "iff" is a quite common abbreviation for "if and only if". There is even a LaTeX-command for that: `$\iff$` produces $\iff$.

Comment: @TMM I wasn't aware of that. To be fair to me though, I am mostly self taught reading pdfs, and sites bla bla bla. Another tidbit added. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you did is correct, as far as I can tell.

Perhaps a shorter solution is that $(a^2 - b^2) - (a-b)(a+b) = ba - ab$. This is $0$ iff the $a$ and $b$ commute. So, the expression $(a^2 - b^2) - (a-b)(a+b)$ is identically $0$ iff the ring is commutative.

Comment: Good catch. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps shorter?... No, for sure!

Answer (score 2):

I think there are not many word necessary.
$$a^2 -b^2 = a^2+ab-ab-b^2=a^2+ab-ba-b^2=a(a+b)-b(a+b)=(a-b)(a+b)$$

Answer (score 0):

It looks good! The only holes are the following typos: $x(a+b)=xa+b$ and $-ba=ab=0$

In fact, you don't even need the substitution $x=a-b$, since you can simply multiply out the right-hand side normally assuming distributivity for the ring!